# Plotting a 3D plane function and a cylinder in the same figure

Tags: plotting

I'm very new to mathematica and I can't figure out this extremely simple thing that I see even in my Multivariable Calculus textbook.  Basically I want to take the two plots below, one of a cylinder and one of a plane, and put them on the same figure.

```
Plot3D[3x+y,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}]
ContourPlot3D[x^2+y^2==10,{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},{z,-10,10}]
```

[image: Super simple cylinder]

[image]

Comment: try also `ContourPlot3D[{x^2 + y^2 == 10, 3 x + y == z}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
  10}, {z, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[.7]]`

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[Plot3D[3 x + y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.75]],
 ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 == 10, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot